# Unable to connect to basic ubuntu ssh server with password authentication - permission denied publickey

Tags: ssh, 20.04, sshd

Title says it all. I followed this guide to the letter:
https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-enable-ssh-on-ubuntu-20-04/
However at the end I was unable to ssh to ubuntu - I get permission denied (publickey).
So I went into my sshd_config and modified the following:
PermitRootLogin yes
PubkeyAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication yes
PermitEmptyPasswords no

everything else I left defaulted from a fresh install of ssh server. However, I still cannot log in via ssh, as I get Permission denied (publickey). I find this odd, considering I have explicitly disabled public key authentication. I even tried using the following ssh command:
ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=password -o PubkeyAuthentication=no myuser@myserver

However I still get the same result. What on earth am I missing? This seems like it should work.
This is in ubuntu 20.04

Comment: I just realized.....I can ssh via the IP address of my server and it works fine. However, if I attempt using the hostname, this issue happens.

Comment: Ok this keeps getting weirder...when I try to ping it, I get this:
a23-202-231-168.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com
which is NOT my device at all. What is this? Why does it have the same name as my hostname? I am using sambashare as the hostname as I am using it primarily as a samba server - is this a common host?

Comment: You better tell us some more about your local area network.  As far as I can determine `23.202.231.168` is `a23-202-231-168.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com`.

Comment: I don't have a clue what that is. However, I did find something interesting. I was attempting this from a terminal in WSL. On a hunch I downloaded putty and tried to ssh in via the hostname from that, and it worked fine! So something is screwy with WSL. I went into the /etc/hosts file and manually added my server/IP (as the IP is static in my network) and now I can ssh using hostname from my WSL terminal. I have no idea what is going on though.

Comment: I can only assume WSL was using some external DNS (Domain Name Service) and got the real answer for something you also seem to use as a local name.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue trying to connect from mint 20.04 to an ubuntu 20.04 server. The `sshd_config` was set up just as you descried on the server.

If you try `ssh -v user@hostname` you may see it trying a bunch of authentication keys, even though they are not in the `config` and you're not using the `-i` at the command line. It keeps trying different keys it finds until the server gets annoyed and closes out the connection.

In this case, try disabling public key authentication on the *client* (temporarily, one-shot at the command line):

```
ssh user@servername -o PubkeyAuthentication=no
```

After doing this, it prompted for a password and successfully logged in. I was also able to use `sshpass -pMYPASSWORD ssh user@servername`

***Example output:***

```
$ sshpass -p<password> ssh -v  <user>@<servername> 
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/<user>/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to <servername> [<servername>] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/<user>/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/<user>/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/<user>/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/<user>/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/<user>/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/<user>/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to <servername>:22 as '<user>'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:r2Ra44NtKxs4WPYKroLMETpd2ebGxUwiKuJdCLqX3fM
debug1: Host '<servername>' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/<user>/.ssh/known_hosts:33
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:Yxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx0 /home/<user>/.ssh/<privatekey>
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:Axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxk <user>@MacBook-Pro.fritz.box
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:4xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxg root@MacBook-Pro.fritz.box
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:qxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxg right@<user>-<computername>-Mint
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:zxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxM right@right-<computername>
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:vxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxc root@unite
Received disconnect from <servername> port 22:2: Too many authentication failures
Disconnected from <servername> port 22
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly, you want to set up ssh access with *password* (as opposed to e.g. keypairs).

#### Other settings than those you mention can be at play in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

You mentioned you had already set these:

```
PermitRootLogin yes
PubkeyAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication yes
PermitEmptyPasswords no
```

**You also** need to set one of these:

```
KbdInteractiveAuthentication yes
  # recent OpenSSH versions

ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
  # less recent OpenSSH versions
```

Further, if the optional setting `AuthenticationMethods` is active, you should probably comment it out - its argument is a list of authentication methods and all must be passed for the login to be allowed.

#### Restart `sshd`

After saving `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, restart `sshd` (SSH server daemon):

```
sudo systemctl disable --now ssh
sudo systemctl enable --now ssh
```

#### Trouble-shooting

To see what authentication methods are attempted, accepted and denied, try to connect to the host with `-v`for verbose output:

```bash
<client>$ ssh -v host
```

From the output you can follow what authentication methods are attempted and the response from the host. E.g. look for lines such as:

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey

debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
```

Comment: Thanks you! This is the only answer that worked for me. Vanilla Ubuntu 22 on Pi 3